# Getting Metro App's thread ID for a keyboardHook

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to set a low level keyboard hook on a Metro App from a classic console application.
My problem is that metro apps can't be hooked with global hooks.
So i'm trying to attach the hook to the specific thread but I don't find it.

For now this is what I have :

```
    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc, ProcessModule tabModule)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("INFO HOOK : Setting hook " + tabModule.ModuleName.ToString());
        var result = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, proc, GetModuleHandle(tabModule.ModuleName), 0);
        Debug.WriteLine("INFO BACK : Hook handle = " + result);
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that in the SetWindowsHookEx function, the 0 means global hook that I'm supposed to replace with the thread ID.
When I try to get the thread ID thtough this:

```
    ProcessThreadCollection threadList = processList[0].Threads;
    Debug.WriteLine("Threads = " + threadList.Count);
    foreach (ProcessThread thread in threadList)
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread = " + thread.Id);
```

I get a count of 40 threads with (of course) the list.

My question is: What thread can I use as the SetWindowsHookEx last parameter to hook the keyboard input from the Windows Store App.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` instead of `WH_KEYBOARD` and [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx), you can hook keyboard for all processes including another store app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no, when I set it to a WH_KEYBOARD_LL, the hook doesn't catch the metro app inputs.
It is documented in MSDN:
"Windows Store app development If dwThreadId is zero, then window hook DLLs are not loaded in-process for the Windows Store app processes and the Windows Runtime broker process unless they are installed by either UIAccess processes (accessibility tools). The notification is delivered on the installer's thread for these hooks:"